Python datetime output +3GMT
Please help me to improve my code.
I'am trying to calculate current time minus 3 minutes, and output should be in Unix Timestamp +3GMT
But instead it prints me utc time (+ 0)
import datetime
import pytz


tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')
ct = datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz)


#TIMESTAMP = (datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz) - datetime.timedelta(minutes=3)).timestamp()
TIMESTAMP = (ct - datetime.timedelta(minutes=3)).timestamp()

print(TIMESTAMP)

I am expecting to calculate current time minus 3 minutes and have an output without digits after "."
My output 1723800379.779615, but should be 1723627579

Did you try int(TIMESTAMP)?

Your example could use a hard-coded datetime.  It will get a different value each time it runs otherwise.  Having a known input and required output helps validation.

Code Correction
dateutil provides more flexible timezone handling compared to pytz.
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import dateutil.tz
tz = dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/Moscow')
ct = datetime.now(tz)
time_minus_3_minutes = ct - timedelta(minutes=3)
timestamp = int(time_minus_3_minutes.timestamp())#Unix timestamp conversion

print(timestamp)

Output
1723801868


This can be done with built-in libraries; although, on Windows zoneinfo still requires the first-party (maintained by CPython core developers) tzdata module which contains the IANA time zone database.  It can be installed via pip install tzdata.  It is a fallback for systems such as Windows that don't have system time zone data installed.
import datetime as dt
import zoneinfo as zi

tz = zi.ZoneInfo('Europe/Moscow')
now = dt.datetime.now(tz=tz)
print(now)  # Actual time
calc = now - dt.timedelta(minutes=3)
ts = int(calc.timestamp())
print(ts)

# Validate that result is 3 minutes earlier with
# no fractional seconds and in the correct time zone.
print(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=tz))

Output:
2024-08-16 20:03:27.921596+03:00
1723827627
2024-08-16 20:00:27+03:00


import datetime
TIMESTAMP = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=3) + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)).timestamp()
print(TIMESTAMP)
Thanks a lot, I solved it like this
